# Installation of TeX Live Portable fails under Linux Debian

Tags: texlive, installing, debian

I attempeted to install the portable version of `texlive` (on an SSD card) on a Linux Debian installation. It started OK, with some files and directories installed, but then error messages:

```
  Installing [0001/3701, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many
    [376k]

  tar: tex/latex/12many/12many.sty: Cannot change  
    ownership to uid 0, gid 0: Operation not permitted

  tar: tlpkg/tlpobj/12many.tlpobj: Cannot change ownership
    to uid 0, gid 0: Operation not permitted

  tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I was doing this as `sudo`, so permissions should not have been a problem. Also, `12many.sty` was installed with ownership `"rw"` for me and `"r"` for others.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be a filesystem on your card which doesn't support ownership and unix attributes. Is it FAT or NTFS?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The file system on the card is vfat.

Comment: vfat doesn't support file ownership. I never installed portable TeXLive, but I'd try the following: first, install it as a user without `sudo`. If that also fails, switch the filesystem to ext4.

Comment: Running as a user without sudo worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the reasons: The `tar` files we distribute have uid/gid set to 0, which is the only reasonable uid/gid that can be employed across all systems. `tar` during the unpack phase tries to restore uid/gid when running as root, but not as user. The `tar` man page says:

```
 -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
       extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
```

Now, as mentioned, if you try to do this on a vfat system, tar will bail out when running as root, while ok when running as user.